# Cant import library after installing via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, import, cocoapods

I am trying to install the library called `[VialerSIPLib][1]` to my project. There were an issue of I am not able reach any code of the pod

I have put the lines to podfile as follows;

```
platform :ios, 13.0

target ...... do 
  pod 'VialerSIPLib'
  #use_frameworks!
end
```

and pod installs the library with 3 more libraries. Throws no error and prints

> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and
>   4 total pods installed. Actual behavior

However, when I try to create a account in `AppDelegate` with line of code `var account:VSLAccount!`, it throws `Use of undeclared type VSLAccount.` A Relative error when I try to import the library. I am just trying to reach all methods and classes from my project.

Example project works well. I was able to make call. I am using MacOS Catalina and iOS version 13.0 and creating the project with `SwiftUI`

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild ?

Comment: yes I had. no chance.

Comment: it still didnt work? Are you using the xcworkspace project ?

Comment: of course, I am using `xcworkspace`.

Comment: Yes I am using swift 4. let me check with Swift 5

Comment: did you import VialerSIPLib

Comment: Yes, when import it says ‘No such Module’

Comment: Ok, I have solved by chance and have idea why did this happen. I tried cleaning the project, then restarting the pc couple times. Afterwards I was able to `import` the lib and call whatever I want. @MohitKumar if you re-answer the question with the previous answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on their installation guide:

> When you are having trouble that your app can't compile because of a
>   linker error. Try this because of the VialerSIPLIB is now requiring
>   git-lfs. Clear the cache of cocoapods which is located at:
>   /Users/$USER/Library/Caches/CocoaPods

Not sure if this is the problem, just a lil' something that might help. [Reference](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4801)

Comment: Yeah ı am aware of that but I do not get such error. It is about git-lfs whilst installing a static dependancy.